# How to apply css in iframe body content : Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I used an iframe for some calculation like this.

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://www.investwell.in/updation/parameter/Calculator/par_retirement_calculatorN.jsp?obgl=eeeeee&amp;fs=14&amp;ol=222222&amp;obgr=dddddddd&amp;or=111111&amp;share=N" width="100%" height="900" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Now, i want to apply css to iframe content using Javascript but i'm unable to get this.

JS:

```
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
  .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .panel-body{background: red !important;}  </style>"));#000000';
});
```

Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong here?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The iframe content is coming from an external domain so you cannot change any of its content (CSS or otherwise) through JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with an iframe. 
That would violate domain isolation ([Same origin policy](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) and would be a massive security hole, as it would allow an attacker to modify portion of an arbitrary website after loading it.
Imagine what I could do if I could modify arbitrary form data after loading your bank's website in a "handy" iframe for you!

The only way to do this would be to replace the iframe with a div, and load the content via javascript with an ajax request (which you can only do if the other page is also on your domain, or the appropriate [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers are set). Of course this would require extensive restructuring of both websites, and more importantly it would require you to have the permission of the target website which I don't suppose you do.
Bear in mind that the same origin policy is in place *exactly* to prevent what you're trying to do, so there's no way around it.

I suggest you find another way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this is part of the [Same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the style of a page displayed in an iframe unless you have **direct access** and therefore ownership of the source html and/or css files.

This is to stop [XSS (Cross Site Scripting)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 0):

**You can apply CSS for iframe content. Follow below steps.**

1. Create a Style Sheet according to your requirement.
2. Create below JavaScript function in the main page.

   ```
          function myFunc() {
          var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
          var style = document.createElement('link');
          style.href = "CSS.css";
          style.rel = "stylesheet";
          style.type = "text/css";
          iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style);
          }
   ```
3. Call JavaScript function at onload event of iframe like below.

   ```
      <iframe id="iframe"  src="test.html" width="100%"></iframe>
   ```
4. Enjoy  :)

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to do this through JavaScript.

Comment: I think it's vice-versa, you can apply styles to iFrame by ONLY using JavaScript and not just a css

Comment: @javaEegen.. but how? can you leave a answer for me?